# Closing ng-href - cross button or auto closing after downloading file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I dynamically show message with link to download some file (it does work):

```
<a ng-href = "{{myCtrl.fileUrl}}" download = "{{myCtrl.file}}">
    {{myCtrl.file}}
</a>
```

How to close (or even better - add cross in right up corner) this message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps :

```
 1. Add ng-hide directive to your anchor tag. Example ng-hide="hideLink"
 2. Call a function on click of download link. Example ng-click="downloadLinkClicked()"
 3. Within the function, set $scope.hideLink = true;
 4. Your download link will be hidden now.
```

Code snippet :

In you `HTML`

```
<a ng-href = "{{myCtrl.fileUrl}}" download = "{{myCtrl.file}}" ng-hide="hideLink" ng-click="downloadLinkClicked()">
    {{myCtrl.file}}
</a>
```

In your `js` controller :

```
$scope.hideLink = false;
    $scope.downloadLinkClicked = function () {
        $scope.hideLink = true;
    }
```

Comment: Tip : You can even add &cross; next to anchor tag and call closeLink() function on click of it.

Comment: Could you edit and show more details ? I am beginner in angularjs.

Comment: See if that helps ?

Comment: Thanks. What about message with cross button ?